# XAMPP 1.7.3 uninstall problem

Tags: windows-xp, php, uninstall, xampp

Error of XAMPP 1.7.3 during uninstalling

> 'CSCRIPT.EXE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> XAMPP uninstall not OK
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

This is the error I'm getting when I try to uninstall XAMPP 1.7.3 from Windows XP...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the folder `C:\Windows\System32` is in the system's PATH environment variable.
To check, go to Start > Run > cmd and type:

```
path
```

If there's no C:\Windows\Sytem32 value somewhere inside the output, you need to add it manually.

To add it, go to Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables > find *Path* in the *System variables* > click Edit.

Prefix `C:\Windows\System32;` to the *Variable value*. After that the uninstall should be able to run.